# Java program isn't showing output on Linux terminal

Tags: java

I'm running a Java program on a Chromebook, and I'm trying to run the file in the Linux terminal. I ran the command `javac Main.java`, but it shows nothing, not an error, but just straight up nothing.

I have Java installed. The file I'm running has no bugs. I did not make a typo. Everything is perfectly right.

Is there something I'm missing?

```
user@penguin:~$ javac Main.java
user@penguin:~$
```

Comment: `javac` just *compiles* the code. You haven't *executed* the program at all. (There's nothing specific to Linux or Chromebooks about this. `javac` is just the compiler, everywhere.) If you then run `java Main` (assuming your `Main` class is in the default package) it will actually execute it.

Comment: @JonSkeet  so then what do I execute?

Comment: You run `java Main` - but ideally, you read through a Java tutorial carefully, as if you've come unstuck at this point, you're very likely to immediately run into another problem that would be better solved by a tutorial than by Stack Overflow.